# htaccess redirect http to https for subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ssl

I use this redirect because my website is inside a subfolder (www.domain.com/subfolder/)

So if someone enters the website, it will load like this: http://domain.com

What do I need to add or change in .htaccess so that it redirects automatically to https://domain.com, counting that the website is at domain.com/subfolder

I have tried various redirect codes, but no success. If someone is kind to point me in the right direction or give me a hint.

Thanks for the help.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule !^subfolder/ subfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: Are you getting a 404 page?